# Cant add custom content type to my new tenant

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, content-type

I created a new tenant for DEV purposes. I create a custom document Content Type. But when I try to add a new template to it, I don't have access, even if I use the same account I created the tenant and I am an admin.

How come?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Custom Scripts enabled in the SharePoint Admin center.

Execute the command bellow with the url for the modern site collection

```
Set-SPOSite -Identity https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/contoso -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0
```

More information about enable custom scripts:

[Enable custom script on modern SharePoint sites](https://sharepoint.handsontek.net/2018/10/28/enable-custom-script-on-modern-sharepoint-sites-using-powershell/)

In addition, you can also refer to these two similar issues:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Office-365-Groups/Unable-to-add-custom-template-to-a-custom-site-content-type-in/m-p/63855

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2112128-access-denied-when-uploading-a-template-to-a-content-type